# Audio not working in Arch Linux, my sound is gone

Tags: linux, archlinux

This is funny because I had exact the same setup before, but I had to send my motherboard and processor to be replaced by guarantee. After that my sound is gone. Especially trying to get the headphone output to work.
My hunch says that NVIDIA's HDMI has something to do with the problem, but I have not been able to pinpoint the problem out yet. I use default DVI cable.

I have reinstalled my Arch Linux a few times but the problem persists.

I have checked the following:

- speaker-test -c2 <- plays and works for some reason. This is the only thing that works.
- aplay test-wav-file.wav <- plays but hear nothing.
- alsamixer (unmuted, fiddled, everything
- asoundconf set-default-card SB (motherboards chip).

---

```
lspci output:  
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia   (Intel HDA) (rev 40)  
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller   (rev a1)  



aplay -l output:  
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****  

card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ls -la /dev/snd/ output: total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 340 Aug 16 15:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 3020 Aug 16 15:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 80 Aug 16 15:25 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 2 Aug 16 15:25 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 8 Aug 16 15:25 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 7 Aug 16 15:25 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 13 Aug 16 15:25 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 4 Aug 16 15:25 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 3 Aug 16 15:39 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 5 Aug 16 15:25 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 6 Aug 16 15:25 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 9 Aug 16 15:25 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Aug 16 15:25 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 Aug 16 15:25 pcmC1D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 12 Aug 16 15:25 pcmC1D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 1 Aug 16 15:25 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Aug 16 15:25 timer
```

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, try the archlinux forums. The knowledge there will be more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try installing PulseAudio

```
sudo pacman -Sy pulseaudio
```

SystemD should detect that it is installed and start it on your next reboot. You should then have sound.

Answer (score 0):

if aplay -l shows no devices, run:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add:

```
options snd_intel_dspcfg dsp_driver=3
```